# image doesn't send to serveur from ionic3

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I try upload multiple images from ionic3 to serveur php but I have error images doesn't send to backend.. I use imagepicker plugin to select multiple images ..

code angular:

```
testfile(){

  for (var l of this.images)
  {
    if(l !== 'K' && l !== 'O')
    {
           this.base64.encodeFile(l).then((base64File: string) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('photo',base64File);

   this.http.post('url api',formData, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res =>

 alert(res),
        err => {
          this.presentToast(err);
        });
  }

  , (err) => {
  this.presentToast(err);
  this.presentToast('error encode');
});
}
}
}
```

also I try send base64File without append to formData and also I try send l (get in loop) but also error in all cases

Comment: describe error and also update more code...

Comment: Any error but response back is empty array and not object File

Comment: imagepicker  plugin give us base64 string..... why you need this.. image array send to the server no need to send one bye one image

Comment: @Utpaul , I try without this.base64.encodeFile but also error :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using Camera plugin and set

```
Camera.PictureSourceType: PHOTOLIBRARY
```